Restrict OPENLDAP record attributes replicated to consumer
I have open LDAP 2.5 running on two servers in multi-master mode. I would like to replicate (most of) this database to a remote site in another country. Due to privacy concerns, I would like to restrict what info is replicated, in particular there are a few fields that I want to exclude from replication. It seems that syncrepl is a pull-oriented process... I can have the consumer "not ask" for all the fields, but there must be some way of excluding fields from replication on the provider end. Unfortunately it probably involves ACL's which I don't have a lot of experience setting up. Can anyone offer suggestions or a tutorial that would show how to do what I want?
I did some reading and to strip out, let's say the "gecos" field from replication, what I think I need is:
On provider:
an ACL rule on my user database {0}mdb something like:
olcAccess: {0}to * by dn.exact="cn=replicator,dc=my,dc=company,dc=com" read by * break

olcAccess: {1}to * attrs=gecos by dn.exact="cn=replicator,dc=my,dc=company,dc=com" none by * break

I'm not sure of which rule has to be read first. Will this do what I want it to? Also, should I use "exattrs=gecos" on my consumer, if I don't will it generate errors?

The above couple of lines work.  The two acl lines have to be reversed, i.e. the attribute has to be refused before read access is granted to the rest of the database.  I was going to delete the post but will leave it here in case others run into the same situation.
And, multiple attributes can be specified with a single 'attrs=' statement, just comma-separate them.
